# How to do multiple page form submission with ajax request

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

The application is to ship items where on 1st page customer fills up information. Then on 2nd page he gets different rate options to choose from. Then on 3rd page he needs to fill up address info. Then on 4th page payment info & so on.

Now let's say customer enter details on the 1st page. I send ajax request to server & get different rates options.
Once I come back in ajax success, I need to change the page to 2nd jsp. Once customer chooses rate options then again make ajax request & get 3rd jsp & so on.

I need to implement UI side of the code without reloading or redirecting the page. Also from 2nd & 3rd jsps I should have a back button to go to the previous page.

Is it possible with only jquery like setting/replacing divs or is there any plugin I could use like twitter bootstrap carousel?

I need some help in ajax success function so that I can go to next or prev jsps with submit & back buttons?
I am using spring MVC framework.

Comment: Use jquery to submit.

Comment: I ma using jquery but what should go inside ajax success function?

Comment: `('#formId').submit();`

Answer (score 2):

I think you are a bit confused about who makes what: you are mixing jsp and ajax, server side computation and client side.

Don't care about jsp or spring. They have nothing to do with what you need: you are going to implement a **single page application**, so jsp and spring will only be in charge of deliver datas to the client, for example, in the form of json (to bind to a template, see jsview) or html (to append a dom element).

Customer enter details on the 1st page, on submit, an ajax call happens. The response of the call will be, as I said above, json or html that will be bind to your document, so now you can show the new data and hide the old one, with bootstrap carousel is ok... and so on for the other pages.

For the back button, if you use only html5 browser you should manipulate the browser history (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history), if not you should use a polyfill like history.js (https://github.com/browserstate/history.js/)

This response is only a clue of a way to do what you need. AngluarJS or ember.js are another keyword you can use to search solutions to your problem.